# Use .htaccess for redirecting mobile and IE/Safari

Tags: .htaccess, internet-explorer, redirect, mobile, safari

since i dont know .htaccess i got a hard time to figure out why my code wont work.
what i want to do is to redirect mobile AND internet-explorer users to the same page.
this is my code:

```
RewriteEngine on


# if the browser accepts these mime-types, it's definitely mobile, or pretending to be
RewriteCond %{HTTP_ACCEPT} "text\/vnd\.wap\.wml|application\/vnd\.wap\.xhtml\+xml" [NC,OR]
# a bunch of user agent tests
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "sony|symbian|nokia|samsung|mobile|windows ce|epoc|opera mini|opera mobi" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "mini|nitro|j2me|midp-|cldc-|netfront|mot|up\.browser|up\.link|audiovox"[NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "blackberry|ericsson,|panasonic|philips|sanyo|sharp|sie-"[NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} .*MSIE.*[NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "portalmmm|blazer|avantgo|danger|palm|series60|palmsource|pocketpc"[NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "smartphone|rover|ipaq|au-mic,|alcatel|ericy|vodafone\/|wap1\.|wap2\.|iPhone|android"[NC]

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://\my-mobile-and-iexplore-site\.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

thats what i'm using at the moment, put together from diffrent sources, but wont work at the moment! thanks for any help, very appreciated!
oh, and i would like to be able to add safari to this list, too! thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by "won't work"? Are mobiles not being redirected? IE8? Both?

Comment: mobiles are redirected, but IE isn't, no matter what version!